# I'm working on chess game using Flutter, i have some difficulties creating a Function to see the valid moves for one of the pieces

Tags: flutter, dart, game-development, 2d-games

I created a grid view and placed all the pieces that I wanted. Then, I moved on to create a function to calculate the valid moves for each piece. I completed most of the function, but I encountered a problem with the bishop piece. This is the function where the error is shown.

`List<List> checkValideMoves(int row ,int col,ChessPiece? piece){
List<List> candidateMoves =  [];
int direction = piece!.isWhite? -1:1;

```
switch(piece.type){
  case ChessPieceType.knight:
    //all eight move that the knight can do 
    var knightMoves = [
      [-2,-1]
      ,[-2,1]
      ,[-1,-2],
      [-1,2],
      [1,-2]
      ,[1,2]
      ,[2,-1],
      [2,1]
    ];
    for(var move in knightMoves){
      var newRow = row + move[0];
      var newCol = col + move[1];
      if(!isInBoard(newRow, newCol)){
        continue;
      }
      if(board[newRow][newCol]!=null){
        if(board[newRow][newCol]!.isWhite != piece.isWhite){
          candidateMoves.add([newRow,newCol]);
        }
        continue;
      }
      candidateMoves.add([newRow,newCol]);
    }
    break;
  case ChessPieceType.bishop:
    //diagonal directions
     var directions = [
      [-1,-1]
      ,[-1,1]
      ,[1,-1],
      [1,1]
    ];
    for(var direction in directions){
      var i =0;
      while(true){
        var newRow = row+i *direction[0];
        var newCol = col+i *direction[1];
        if(!isInBoard(newRow, newCol)){
          break;
        }
        if(board[newRow][newCol]!=null){
          if(board[newRow][newCol]!.isWhite != piece.isWhite){
            candidateMoves.add([newRow,newCol]);
          }
          break;
        }
      candidateMoves.add([newRow,newCol]);
      i++;
      }
    }
    break;
}

return candidateMoves;
```

}`

It seems like the issue lies in the part of your code that calculates valid moves for the bishop piece.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chess](https://pub.dev/packages/chess) flutter package

```
String move1 = 'e3';
String move2 = 'e4';

final success = chess.move(<String, String?>{
        'from': move1,
        'to': move2,
      });
```

and check if success is true or false.